# How to enable trace.axd in ASP.NET core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Our app is based on ASP.NET Core 2.0. It works fine in development environment but we see an oauth error when published to production.

All the documentation on asp.net core seems to point to using `ILoggingxxx` interfaces. The examples I found typically call `logging.AddConsole()` method so that the log lines can be viewed in VIsual Studio debug window. I am wondering if the good old trace.axd is still available under asp.net core. If so, I would appreciate the steps to enable tracing. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

`trace.axd` is exclusive to applications based on .NET Framework and ASP.NET 4.x. It is not available in ASP.NET Core applications at all.